# Single Button to scrollTop(); though sections on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, scrolltop

I have a webpage that is broken into different sections.

I've came across a lot of help and tutorials on how to create a navigation/side navigation to animate the html body to animate and scroll to the top of a `div` once the button is clicked.

What I haven't found is a way to combine all the functions into one nice compact button. (I'm thinking an arrow)

**html** will look something like this

```
<div class="section" id="section-one">
</div>
<div class="section" id="section-two">
</div>
<div class="section" id="section-three">
</div>
<div class="section" id="section-four">
</div>
<div class="section" id="section-five">
</div>
<span class="arrow">&uarr;</span>
```

**Css** will look a little like this

```
.section{
  height:800px;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  position:relative;
}
.arrow{
  display:block;
  position:fixed;
  top:25px;
  right:25px;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, transform 1s;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transition:opacity 0.5s, transform 1s;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
}

.arrow.is-up{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

I'm hoping to be able to click the arrow and scroll to each section one after the other. Then once it is on the last section `section-five` I can `addClass('is-up');` which will animate the arrow 180deg and add a new function which will then scroll to the very top of the webpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// get the offset of your '.section' container
var bodyOffset = $('body').offset().top;

// listen for click events
$('.arrow').on('click', function(){

    // count sections and assume that current section is the first section
    var sectionCount = $('.section').length;
    var currentSection = 0;

    // iterate thru elements to determine what section you are in
    for(var i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++){
        var currentScrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
        var thisSectionOffset = $(".section").eq(i).offset().top - bodyOffset;
        if(currentScrollPosition >= thisSectionOffset){
            currentSection = i;
        }
    }

    // determine what the new section should be
    var newSection = (currentSection+1 > sectionCount-1) ? 0 : currentSection+1;

    // animate arrow
    if(newSection == sectionCount-1){
        $('.arrow').addClass('is-up')
    } else {
        $('.arrow').removeClass('is-up')        
    }

    // scroll to the new section
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".section").eq(newSection).offset().top
    }, 400);

});
```

Here is a fiddle that uses a background gradient to help demonstrate the scrolling effect: https://jsfiddle.net/yotaajop/1/

Comment: Thank you for you response, Sorry about the delayed reply.

You have provided me with exactly what I am looking for, appreciate the explanations throughout the code too. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/h4ja54uh/3/

On arrow click, determines which section is the next section and animates scroll to it.  If we're on the last section, flip the arrow.  If there is no next section, go back to top.

```
$('.arrow').click(function() {
    $(document.body).animate({
        scrollTop: (function() {
            // Get the next section (top of section is below current scroll)
            var $next = $('.section').filter(function(i, e) {
                return $(document.body).scrollTop() < $(e).offset().top;
            });

            // Reset the arrow
            $('.arrow').removeClass('is-up');

            // See how many sections we have left
            switch ($next.length) {
                // We're past the last section, go to top.
                case 0:
                    return $('.section').first().offset().top;
                // Last section, flip that arrow!
                case 1:
                    $('.arrow').addClass('is-up');
                    // Falls through on purpose.
                    // We flip the arrow, but we still want to scroll.
                // Scroll to next section.
                default:
                    return $next.first().offset().top;
            }
        })()
    });
});

$(document.body).animate({
    scrollTop: $('.section').first().offset().top
});
```

Comment: Thank you for you response, Sorry about the delayed reply.

You have provided me with exactly what I am looking for, as you can see there are two answers to my question, is there much of a difference between the answers, as in is one better suited than the other or? Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to have full screen pages, have you consider using my fullpage.js library?

The plugin provides plenty of functions and within them you can one to make your button `moveSectionDown` or `moveSectionUp`.